# extjs treepanel: expand() & expandChildNodes()

Tags: extjs, nodes, expand, treenode, treepanel

If I write:

```
rootNode.expand()
```

I can only get access to the children nodes of this rootNode, but can't get access to the grandchildren nodes of this rootNode. I have to write:

```
rootNode.expandChildNodes()
```

in order to acheive it.

Is there another way to obtain the grandchildren or further children nodes even if the tree is collapsed? other than using `node.eachChild()` function?
I tried:

```
rootChildNode.firstChild
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtJS 4x has `expandAll()` method on the Tree Panel component. This will expand every node recursively.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to expand to a partcular level then in that case:

```
           expandTo:function(level){

                    treePanel.collapseAll();
                    treePanel.getRootNode().cascadeBy(function (node) {

                          if (node.getDepth() < level) { node.expand(); }
                          if (node.getDepth() == level) { return false; }
                     });
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get to the descendants is to use `node.expand(true)`, where node is the root node.  Similarly, you can take any node within the tree and expand all of its descendant nodes using this same code.  A common usage is for the selected node.